# “git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified” error in Python 3.5

Tags: python, git

I am trying to lemmatize a Latin text using Python 3.5 in Pycharm 5.0.4 with the CLTK library, but there seems to be a problem with Git. I get the error `git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified` among other errors I believe are related—see below for the full output. I have tried adding a Git repository to the project folder and adding the git.exe path to version control but that seems to have done nothing. What can I do to get Git to work properly—please keep in mind that I am a complete neophyte when it comes to Python in particular and not very experienced with programming in general.

Code:

```
from cltk.stem.lemma import LemmaReplacer
from cltk.stem.latin.j_v import JVReplacer
from cltk.corpus.utils.importer import CorpusImporter
corpus_importer = CorpusImporter('latin')
corpus_importer.import_corpus('latin_text_latin_library')
corpus_importer.import_corpus('latin_models_cltk')

#corpus_importer.import_corpus('phi5', '~/PHI5/')
#t.convert_corpus(corpus='phi5')

j = JVReplacer()
lemmatizer = LemmaReplacer('latin')
In = open("CIC.txt","rt")
Out = open("CIC4.txt","wt")
text = In.read()
text = text.lower()
text = j.replace(text)
Out.write(str(lemmatizer.lemmatize(text)))

In.close()
Out.close()
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\python.exe "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py" --multiproc --qt-support --client 127.0.0.1 --port 58508 --file C:/Users/Rune/PycharmProjects/untitled/Pucker.py
pydev debugger: process 14648 is connecting

Connected to pydev debugger (build 143.1919)
--- Logging error ---
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 604, in execute
    **subprocess_kwargs
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 950, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1220, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydev_monkey.py", line 387, in new_CreateProcess
    return getattr(_subprocess, original_name)(appName, patch_arg_str_win(commandLine), *args)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cltk\corpus\utils\importer.py", line 134, in import_corpus
    Repo.clone_from(git_uri, target_dir, depth=1)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\repo\base.py", line 885, in clone_from
    return cls._clone(git, url, to_path, GitCmdObjectDB, progress, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\repo\base.py", line 826, in _clone
    v=True, **add_progress(kwargs, git, progress))
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 450, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args, **kwargs: self._call_process(name, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 878, in _call_process
    return self.execute(make_call(), **_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\git\cmd.py", line 607, in execute
    raise GitCommandNotFound(str(err))
git.exc.GitCommandNotFound: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 980, in emit
    msg = self.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 830, in format
    return fmt.format(record)
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 567, in format
    record.message = record.getMessage()
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\logging\__init__.py", line 330, in getMessage
    msg = msg % self.args
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
Call stack:
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 2411, in <module>
    globals = debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None, is_module)
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1802, in run
    launch(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm 5.0.4\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Rune/PycharmProjects/untitled/Pucker.py", line 5, in <module>
    corpus_importer.import_corpus('latin_text_latin_library')
  File "C:\Users\Rune\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\cltk\corpus\utils\importer.py", line 136, in import_corpus
    logger.error("Git clone of '%s' failed: '%s'", (git_uri, e))
Message: "Git clone of '%s' failed: '%s'"
Arguments: (('https://github.com/cltk/latin_text_latin_library.git', GitCommandNotFound('[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified',)),)

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can manually download the corpus from `https://github.com/cltk/latin_models_cltk` and place it in the 
`~/cltk_data/latin/model/` folder (so `~/cltk_data/latin/model/latin_models_cltk/lemmata/` is an existing folder afterwards). Then you should be able to run the following just fine:

```
from cltk.stem.lemma import LemmaReplacer
LemmaReplacer('latin').lemmatize('some_latin_here')
```

For the same in Greek, just replace the 'latin' by 'greek' *everywhere* in these instructions. I imagine (but haven't tried) that it works the same for other languages too.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I will test it as soon as possible and give due credit.

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that CLTK does not work with any Python version below 3.6, at least as of August 2017. I had a devil of a time getting 3.6 installed on Ubuntu (Ubuntu linus running dual boot from my PC laptop) but eventually got it to work. Also I specifically solved the problem that OP articulates above by following the instructions at https://disiectamembra.wordpress.com/2016/07/01/current-state-of-the-cltk-latin-lemmatizer/. Good luck!